# Do you fall faster alone in Apex Legends?

Tags: apex-legends

Some of my friends think you fall much faster alone in Apex. Is that true or can we stay grouped and obtain the same speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, no.

But your angle can make the whole difference. And I think the game, in the 'splitting away' sequence goes, if you are on the left for example, left and down a little.

So it looks like you are going a little faster, but its because the game just goes a little bit more towards down when splitting up.